# How to select rows of DataFrame based on specific value and create a list of lists from them

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a set of tuples that I want then to do some matching operations later. Here is my df:
[image]
To get these pairs, I need to extract them from a the 'subject' column of the Dataframe called diff based on a specific condition:

1. the 'object' column must have a value belonging to a list of values extracted from the diff Dataframe
2. the 'predicate' column must be equal to

> http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment

Then, for each matching term, I want to create the list of candidates. For instance, for all the terms whose comment is 'A part of something' create a list, e.g., [Book,Booklet,Article] or any suitable datastructure, because then I want to find whether they are similar using nltk.wordnet.

Here is the code:

```
    import re
    ont1 = pd.read_csv('1.tsv',sep='\t',names=['subject','predicate','object'])
    ont2 = pd.read_csv('2.tsv',sep='\t',names=['subject','predicate','object'])
#create the diff df that contains the rows not shared in the dfs    
diff = pd.concat([ont1,ont2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
#create a list of the unique values to act as a condition to create the set of matching candidates
    terms = list(ont_diff['object'].unique())
    for term,index in enumerate(terms):
        maps = []
        uri=str(diff.loc[(diff['object']==terms[0]) & (diff['predicate']== 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment'),'subject'])
#use re.sub to clean the url for easiness
        uri=re.sub(' http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/tests/101/','',uri)
#remove the first item fo the terms list to advance a new term in the look up above        
terms.pop(0)
        maps.append(uri)
        print(maps)
```

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code/data on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You want items from `object` only if they are found in `subject`?

Comment: Not exactly, I want items of 'subject' only when found 'object' whenever 'object' matches one of the items from the 'terms' list. Notice that there should be more than one match for each object value, and I want to store each set of values as one list.